# why does spdy not function here with nginx 1.5.10?

Tags: nginx, centos6, spdy

i have compiled nginx 1.5.10 with the spdy module on centos 6.5 and it is operating without a problem, as far as i know except, that spdy is apparently not being used.

i have added the 'spdy' option to the listen directive in nginx.conf and restarted the server, yet the various spdy checking methods, such as the firefox plugin that is available and also the website: https://spdycheck.org/
both show that spdy is not being used on my site.

the line in nginx.conf is:

listen 443 ssl spdy default_server;

i saw this thread: [How to set up SPDY Protocol over Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152775/how-to-set-up-spdy-protocol-over-nginx)

and looked to see if i needed to change the DAEMON or PATH lines in /etc/init.d/nginx - yet in my versions those lines are not present at all.

the output of nginx -V is:

nginx version: nginx/1.5.10
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_spdy_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g'

any tips welcomed!

Comment: i found why spdycheck wasn't showing the site as spdy enabled. the ssl encryption cypher suite was mis-configured.
however, the firefox plugin still is not lit green to show 100% spdy.

Comment: What version of firefox do you use?

Comment: v 26.0 linux mint debian edition 64bit

Comment: can you paste the output of `nginx -V` command, so it would show all the option with which you have compiled nginx? It would give us better insight.

Comment: ok yes, i added the output of nginx -V to the question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPDY/3.1 isn't supported by Firefox 26. The support was added to Firefox in version 27, see [release notes](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/27.0/releasenotes/).

Comment: aha ok - 27 isn't available for auto-update for me yet - so the add-in was a 'wild goose chase' ;)
thanks for the tip.

Comment: except... the plugin offers a green symbol for facebook in firefox 26.. so.. there is more to this than just spdy 3.1 not being supported in firefox 26.

Comment: oh, i thought nginx would fallback to an earlier spdy format if the browser was not compatible with the higher one. (only since that is how other standards usually are)